# R plot multiple line plots (3) against single bar plot

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot multiple line plots against a single bar plot (in this example it's grouped but doesn't have to be) but I'm running into some issues with left y-axis resizing in strange ways. It seems ok-ish when there are two lines, but then extends the axis out when there are more so the scale is wrong and doesn't line up with the bars.

I need to end up with a situation where I can customise the labels on both the left and right y-axes, hence the use of `axis` at the bottom of the code. In the real implementation I'll be dynamically using 'M' for million or 'K' for thousand on the left, and '%' on the right.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
x = c("a","b","c","d") 
y= cbind(c(50,40,30,20), c(40,30,20,10)) 
y2 = c(0.80,0.65,0.75,0.50)
y3 = c(0.30,0.20,0.50,0.60)
y4 = c(0.20,0.30,0.40,0.45) 
#
par(mar=c(5,8,3,5))
bp <- barplot(t(y), beside=TRUE, las=1, names.arg=x, axes=TRUE, ylim=c(0,max(y)+10),         labels=c("0","10 M","20 M","30 M","40 M","50 M","60 M")) 
xlim <- c(floor(min(bp)), ceiling(max(bp))) 
# 
par(new=T) 
plot(colMeans(bp), y2, type="o", col="black", lwd=3, lty=1, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="",   ylab="", xlim = xlim) 
points(colMeans(bp), y2, pch=20)

par(new=T) 
plot(colMeans(bp), y3, type="o", col="red", lwd=3, lty=1, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="",   ylab="", xlim = xlim) 
points(colMeans(bp), y3, pch=20)

par(new=T) 
plot(colMeans(bp), y4, type="o", col="red", lwd=3, lty=1, xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim = xlim) 
points(colMeans(bp), y4, pch=20)

axis(side=2,  at=c(0,0.10,0.20,0.30,0.40,0.50,0.60), labels=c("0","10 M","20 M","30 M","40 M","50 M","60 M"), las=1, pos=0.555)
axis(side=4, pretty(c(0,max(y2))), ylim=c(0,max(y2)), col='black', ylab='', las=1 )
```

Comment: You have a warning here based on using `labels` in your first `barplot` call. You should fix this in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `lines()` argument for the second and third line, the everything works fine. Here is an example for the third Line:

```
#par(new=T) 
lines(colMeans(bp), y4, type="o", col="red", lwd=3, lty=1) 
points(colMeans(bp), y4, pch=20)
```